# Not able to set group and permissions using udev rule

Tags: udev

I written simple rule for detecting the ADU208 relay device and create its device file.

```
#Creat device file for ADU208, USB relay.
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="adutux1", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0a07", ATTRS{idProduct}=="00d0", GROUP="ankur", MODE:="0666"
```

I see file being created in `/dev/adutux1` but permission is not what i am expecting and the group also is not also not what I am expecting.

```
ankur@:/etc/udev/rules.d $ ll /dev/adutux1 
crw------- 1 root root 180, 1 Nov 13 13:59 /dev/adutux1
```

my ubuntu version is as mentioned below

```
Linux ankurs-ubuntu-machine 4.4.0-96-generic #119~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 13 08:40:48 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Can someone point what is wrong with the rule I mentioned above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted udev and disconnected usb cable and connected back. It seems to work. I kind of not sure if I had done that before or not. I tried multiple rules and combination so I might have missed when I got the right rule.
It seems to work now.